# How to serialize a Protobuf object to a byte array in Swift

Tags: swift, serialization, arrays, protocol-buffers

How do I serialize a protobuf (in my case, I am using them for gRPC) to a byte array in Swift?

Comment: Will this work for you? https://github.com/alexeyxo/protobuf-swift.

Comment: Not exactly, I already have the protobuf made, I just need to know how to convert it back to NSData

Comment: I see the protobuf-swift package has both serialization (`person.data() //return NSData`) and deserialization interface (`parseFromData`)

Comment: Oh yeah I figured it out too, it's actually quite simple, with just any protobuf object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the serialized byte array:

```
proto.data()
```

To convert back to protobuf, most protobuf objects will have an constructor like

```
User(data: userData, error: errorPointer)
```